# NodeJs Auto start in business server with systemd as different user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, deployment

I have my business app running in **Development env** and inside that, 2 folders named **Client** and **Backend**.
Client (ReactJS) running in port 5000
Backend (Node.JS) running in Port 6000
Server Nginx.
So in Nginx default.conf file, listening 80 and I've proxy_pass http://localhost:5000.
Its working fine in the Development.

Please note, some redirections are configured like **${host}:3000/xxx** in the backend and client scripts

But while doing the production deployment, I found difficulty in doing so.
I have the static build client file and placed it in the nginx root folder.
Below is the .conf file

```
server {
    listen       80;
        listen          5000;
    server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/client/build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}

location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
}


}
```

I Also have SSO enabled, when I navigate the address, it send the index.html file which is the login page.
When I press login, first it will navigate to "/login/abc/" which is routed in "backend" script.
But it responds with **404** error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are using proxy_pass 6000 not 5000 is that normal?

Comment: my backend running at 6000. so whatever request comes other than "/" should goto the 6000 port.

Comment: You have a named route `@backend`, where does that go?  Also, your second location will only match something strictly alphanumeric, eg `/a5d8G3J`, not any further slashes, dots, or anything else, so if you expect any kind of path or filename.ext here, it will not be found.